# Is the complementary log-log the natural parametrization of the median survival from the KM figure?

Tags: median, kaplan-meier

When running Kaplan Meier figures and obtaining 95% CIs for quantile statistics, like the median, you usually have the option to supply one of a few possible options for variance estimates. I've been exploring the Bartholomew estimate which is on the linear scale. However, in manuscripts, I notice the median is often reported with a non-symmetric 95% CI, and the authors never seem to explain in the methods on exactly what scale the median is calculated. I would back transform the value and calculate differences to see what transformation, i.e. a log or clog-log, gives a symmetric interval; but due to rounding error I can never be quite sure; manuscripts typically only show one decimal place.

I know you can produce correct and symmetric intervals for an estimate on any scale (provided some minimal assumptions are met), but typically a particular transform is preferred because it is a "natural parametrization" (using GLM words) or at least and efficient transformation (meaning it achieves a Cramer Rao lower bound). Is there any such scale for the median that is expected to hit a minimum variance, hence "tightest" interval?

Comment: Thought-provoking (+1). The Kaplan-Meier estimate doesn't explicitly evaluate time, so any dilation or contraction of the time scale between event times would give the same model. Could you please say more about what a "tightest" interval then might represent? Maybe encompassing the minimum number of observed events?